# Select maximum/minimum with another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there is a way to select the maximum of value + another column without the use of **TOP** and **order by**?

Assuming that we have a list of people and their ages, we want take the oldest/youngest. I want to select the name + the age. Even If it happens that we want to group them by name, that won't work.

```
SELECT   nom,
         max(age) 
from     Agents
group by nom

╔════════╦═════╗
║  Name  ║ Age ║
╠════════╬═════╣
║ John   ║ 200 ║
║ Bob    ║ 150 ║
║ GSkill ║ 300 ║
║ Smith  ║ 250 ║
║ John   ║ 400 ║
║ Zid    ║ 300 ║
║ Wick   ║ 250 ║
║ Smith  ║ 140 ║
╚════════╩═════╝
```

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result. (All as well formatted text, not images.)

Comment: why it doesn't work? any error message? unexpected result?

Comment: @jarlh I added the table. I want to have the oldest guy on the list. (with both name and age).

Comment: @McNets It result in having the maximum of each group and not the maximum of everything.

Comment: Also specify the expected result as formatted text!

Comment: your query doesn't group any record unless there is more than one record by Name.

Comment: @McNets We have john twice.

Comment: @jarlh expecting to have "John   ║ 400 ║" as result because he is the oldest. (age 400)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) or [DENSE_RANK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql). For example, if you have to show those  employees having the MIN and MAX salary then you could use following SQL statement:

```
SELECT x.Name, x.Salary, 
    IIF(x.RowNumMIN = 1, 1, 0) AS IsMin,
    IIF(x.RowNumMAX = 1, 1, 0) AS IsMax
FROM (
    SELECT x.Name, x.Salary,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY x.Salary ASC) AS RowNumMIN,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY x.Salary DESC) AS RowNumMAX
    FROM dbo.SourceTable AS x
) AS x
WHERE x.RowNumMIN = 1 OR x.RowNumMAX = 1
```

If there are two or more people having the same min or max salary and you have to show all of then you could use DENSE_RANK function instead of ROW_NUMBER.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query --

```
;WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT [NAME]
        ,AGE
        ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (
            ORDER BY AGE DESC
            ) AS Older
        ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (
            ORDER BY AGE ASC
            ) AS Younger
    FROM tblSample
    )
SELECT [NAME] + ': ' + CAST(AGE AS VARCHAR(50))
FROM CTE
WHERE Older = 1 OR Younger = 1
```